# Convergence issue in electronics text

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm currently reading a book on communications circuits and I'm completely stuck on one particular derivation given in the book.  This isn't homework and I'm definitely no mathematician.  I believe it's more of a maths issue which is why I've posted here as opposed to the electronics stack site.

Here's the section of interest from the book:

[Equation Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV8em.png)

Basically, the author claims that for high values of omega, the expression:

$$\Omega = Q\frac{\left ( 1-\frac{1}{\Omega } \right )^{2}}{1-\frac{1}
{n\Omega }}$$

reduces to

$$\Omega = Q + \frac{1}{n}$$

and for the life of me, I can't see how!  Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \Omega  = Q{{\left( {1 - {1 \over \Omega }} \right)^{\,2} } \over {\left( {1 - {1 \over {n\Omega }}} \right)}}  \cr 
  & {Q \over \Omega }\left( {1 - {1 \over \Omega }} \right)^{\,2}  = 1 - {1 \over {n\Omega }}  \cr 
  & 1 - {1 \over n}\left( {{1 \over \Omega }} \right) = Q\left( {{1 \over \Omega }} \right)\left( {1 - 2\left( {{1 \over \Omega }} \right) + \left( {{1 \over \Omega }} \right)^{\,2} } \right)  \cr 
  & 1 - \left( {{1 \over n} + Q} \right)\left( {{1 \over \Omega }} \right) \approx 0 + O\left( {\left( {{1 \over \Omega }} \right)^{\,2} } \right)\quad \left| {\;{1 \over \Omega } \to 0} \right.  \cr 
  & {1 \over \Omega } \approx {1 \over {{1 \over n} + Q}}\quad \left| {\;{1 \over \Omega } \to 0} \right.  \cr 
  & \Omega  \approx {1 \over n} + Q\quad \left| {\;\Omega  \to \infty } \right. \cr} 
$$

Comment: Gah! You made it look so easy! Much appreciated.

Comment: @leapy3ar: glad to help. Probably you were not seeing it as  $1/\Omega=..$:  many times the " trick" is inverting ! ...